# How to use an alias while sending mail on linux?

Tags: linux, email

I have a shell script which sends out a mail at the end of its processing about the status. I am using the command -

`mail -s "MAIL_SUBJECT" "tom@my_domain.com" < "MAIL_TEXT"`

This mail is being sent from an email id like `user@<machine_name>.my_domain.local`.

Is it possible to use an alias while sending these mails ?

Something like `process.name@my_domain.com`?

If yes how do we do it ?

Comment: [so] is about proramming, your question is not; you might try [su], where you can find e.g. [this](http://superuser.com/questions/583210/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-r` option to mention the from address.

```
mail -r "process.name@my_domain.com" -s "MAIL_SUBJECT" "tom@my_domain.com" < "MAIL_TEXT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of `mail` have options for this, but they are not universally portable. If your needs are simple, just write your own `sendmail` wrapper.

```
cat - MAIL_TEXT << ____HERE | sendmail -oi tom@example.com
From: Some Alias <process-noeeply@example.com>
Subject: MAIL_SUBJECT

____HERE
```

The empty line after the headers is significant. Sendmail will fill in (what it thinks are) sensible defaults for the headers you don't specify.

It doesn't have to be a proper Sendmail; most MTAs ship a "sendmail" binary which (more or less) supports the traditional Sendmail command-line API.

If you need MIME or other bells and whistles, maybe look at `mutt` instead.

Answer (score 0):

-r doesn't do anything IF you have not set :

```
FromLineOverride=Yes
```

in /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf (for debian at least) see -> https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssmtp.conf ["FromLineOverride
Specifies whether the From header of an email, if any, may override the default domain. The default is ''no''."]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).